# Excel prefix formula F#

Tags: excel, f#

I have a simple Excel spreadsheet where each cell either contains nothing, a value, or a simple 2 argument formula of the form:

> Function(Cell,Cell),  (e.g. cell A3 might have the formula "=A1 + A2")

I would like to be able to open an Excel file using F# and for any cell get:

1 - null  (because the cell has no value and no formula)

2 - decimal or string (for a value)

3 - a tuple of (string,string string) where the first value is the function 
(e.g. "+" and the 2nd and 3rd part of the tuple is the cell name (e.g. "A1" and "A2")

So: Get("A1") and Get("A2") would both return a double, but Get("A3") would return a tuple ("+","A1","A2")

How would I do this in F# ?

Comment: Don't have a proper answer, but for the internal representation I would use a discriminated union, and for the parsing regular expressions, where depending on what the regex matches you create any of the possible values of the union. 
I'm thinking, though, that this may not be sufficient if you want to be able to parse arbitrary Excel formulas, and you'd want to look into fslex to tokenise.
Would be interesting to see an elaborate implementation of this from one of the experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get a reference to a worksheet object (after starting excel and opening the file with your data), you can use the `Range` member to get a specified cell. Then you can use `Value2` property to get a value (e.g. string/double), which also returns the result of a formula. To get the formula, you can use `Formula` member.

I didn't find any good way for testing whether the value is automatically calculated or not, but you can check if the `Formula` value starts with the `=` character. If you really only need as simple formulas as the one you describe (without parentheses etc.) then a simple regular expression should do the trick:

```
let reg = new Regex("=([A-Z]+[0-9]+)([^A-Z0-9]+)([A-Z]+[0-9]+)")

let getInfo (cell:Range) =
  let formula = cell.Formula.ToString().Replace(" ", "")
  match formula.StartsWith("="), cell.Value2 with
  | true, _ -> 
      let g = reg.Match(formula).Groups
      Formula(g.Item(1),g.Item(2),g.Item(3))
  | :? float as n -> Float(n)
  | :? string as s -> String(s)
  | _ -> Empty
```

This returns a value of the following data type which covers all your cases:

```
type CellInfo = 
  | Empty
  | Float of float
  | String of string
  | Formula of string * string * string
```

BTW: To load an excel in F# Interactive, you need something like this:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll"

// Run Excel as a visible application
let app = new ApplicationClass(Visible = true) 
// Create new file using the default template
let workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet) 
// Get the first worksheet
let worksheet = (workbook.Worksheets.[1] :?> _Worksheet)
```

Comment: Is a cell a calculated cell when the formula string and string representation are not equal?

Comment: if you put a single quote `'` before `=` then a formula and a value are equal (and many people do that often to mute, but not erase a calculation). Range has a property .HasFormula for such a check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.hasformula(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This really gave me an idea and I tried using FsLex/FsYacc to process your Excel cells. It's maybe not exactly what you imagined, but it may be useful and it's also not very big. Basically, the code I wrote runs like this:

```
let teststrings = [ "1002";
                    "=SUM(B2:B12)";
                    "=A1+AVERAGE(B2:B4)";
                    "=B3+G7";
                    "=MIN(MEAN(A3:A20))";
                    "=A1+B4*C6"
                    ];

teststrings |> List.iter (fun s -> (convert s |> printfn "%A" s))
```

and the output looks like

"1002"
"(SUM,(RANGE,B2,B12))"
"(+,A1,(AVERAGE,(RANGE,B2,B4)))"
"(+,B3,G7)"
"(MIN,(MEAN,(RANGE,A3,A20)))"
"(+,A1,(*,B4,C6))"

The whole thing is too big to put in this box, but have a look [here](http://www.codingforfood.com/2010/09/lispifying-excel-cells-with-fslexfsyacc.html).